# jquery li a click img src replace (not togggle)

Tags: jquery, image, replace, click, src

```js
$(function() {

  $("#gnb li a").on("click", function() {
    $(this).find("img").attr("src", $(this).find("img").attr("src").replace("normal.svg", "press.svg"));
  });
  //not working
});
```

```css
#gnb {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 49px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#gnb li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 20%;
}

#gnb li:nth-of-type(1) {
  left: 0%
}

#gnb li:nth-of-type(2) {
  left: 20%
}

#gnb li:nth-of-type(3) {
  left: 40%;
  top: -15px;
}

#gnb li:nth-of-type(3) img {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#gnb li:nth-of-type(4) {
  left: 60%
}

#gnb li:nth-of-type(5) {
  left: 80%
}

#gnb li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 49px;
}

#gnb li a img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="gnb">
  <li>
    <a href="../contents/shops.html"><img src="../images/gnb_btn1_normal.svg" alt="coupon"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="../contents/history.html"><img src="../images/gnb_btn2_normal.svg" alt="useage"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="home">
    <a href="../contents/meal_tickets.html"><img src="../images/gnb_home_normal.svg" alt="home"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="../contents/settings.html"><img src="../images/gnb_btn3_normal.svg" alt="setting"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="../contents/information.html"><img src="../images/gnb_btn4_normal.svg" alt="info"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

li>a click, each img src replace - I want
but not working this code.
what is the problem?

Comment: It must be redirecting based on `href`

Comment: As you have "href" with each hyperlink so it will redirect to the page instead of changing the image, What you want exactly?

Comment: I want href change OK, img change Ok..

Comment: THis is because your `.replace("normal.svg", "press.svg")` is for the exact word. What you need is a regex, because your image name hase also `../images/gnb_btn1_` part.

Comment: Is href is necessary?

Comment: yes, I want to href change and img src replace..

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

```
$('#gnb li a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('img').attr('src').replace('../images/gnb_btn2_normal.svg', '../images/gnb_btn2_press.svg'));
});
```

EDIT :
Added support for href too

```
$('#gnb li a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('img').attr('src').replace('../images/gnb_btn2_normal.svg', '../images/gnb_btn2_press.svg'));
    $(this).attr('href', 'press'));
});
```

Comment: So, you will need two lines. 
I edit my answer.
But not sure if I have undersood!
You will that href is going to another page?

Comment: yes, href is going to another page and img src replace, too.

Comment: so, you can't go to another page and change image on this. because after reload all is reset !! Unless you laod page in a new tab/window !

Comment: So, if I understand, what you want to do is to change image for each page allready visited?